# SafetyNet Attestation fails Flutter Firebase Phone Authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, safetynet-api

I am working on one of my flutter project and trying to add firebase phone authentication but I  encountered with the error related to safetynet.Whereas i am able to use other authentication methods e.g. SignInWithEmailAndPassword. Whenever I am calling my phoneLogin function i am getting the error. I have already installed google play service on my emulator.

### CODE

```
        Future phoneLogin(String phone) async {
        BuildContext context;
        try {
          await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
              phoneNumber: '+91$phone',
              timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30),
              verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credentials) async {
                await auth.signInWithCredential(credentials);
              },
              verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exception) {},
              codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forcedResendingToken]) {
                // print('1')
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => OtpPage(phone: phone),
                  ),
                );
              },
              codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String abc) {});
          return null;
        } catch (e) {
          return null;
        }
      }
```

### ERROR

```
    E/zzbf    ( 6483): SafetyNet Attestation fails basic integrity.
    I/zzkn    ( 6483): Provider GmsCore_OpenSSL not available
    W/System  ( 6483): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
    D/AndroidRuntime( 6483): Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483): Process: com.oneobit.greenobit, PID: 6483
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/browser/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent$Builder;
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:13)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztw.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:7)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztw.onPostExecute(Unknown Source:2)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:199)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~VMK8TkW9ozBJD9t7dnRn8g==/com.oneobit.greenobit-EtKxl5CBj6rDZiliq4I1ZQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~VMK8TkW9ozBJD9t7dnRn8g==/com.oneobit.greenobit-EtKxl5CBj6rDZiliq4I1ZQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~VMK8TkW9ozBJD9t7dnRn8g==/com.oneobit.greenobit-EtKxl5CBj6rDZiliq4I1ZQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 6483):    ... 12 more
    I/Process ( 6483): Sending signal. PID: 6483 SIG: 9
    Lost connection to device.
```

I have already updated SHA256 key to my Firebase console.

Comment: can I see your android/app/build.gradle ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firebase have updated certain things one of them is **they have included captcha verification before sending the code or OTP to mobile devices**.

**To solve this issue see bellow:**

add the following to `project/android/app/build.gradle`

```
implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
```

add this in the dependencies section ...

```
dependencies {

implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
///
}
```

you can find the latest version here: [android browser](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/browser) .

**REASON:**

The app tries to verify the captcha and send the code, for that it tries to launch a browser but because of the missing implementation it fails to load a browser and crashes the application.

Comment: Glad to hear @HimanshuRai   If this answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: `E/zzbf    ( 9275): SafetyNet Attestation fails basic integrity.
W/System  ( 9275): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.`

Comment: I am on it , but you will have to wait a little :)

Comment: hey i got my code work... i just passed wrong build context to navigator. thanks